# How to override block layout in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, module, block

I am using simplenews module to multiple subscription for post
simplenews module provide a block section, but i need to change layout of design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is part of the code of "function template_preprocess_block(&$variables)"

```
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__' . $variables['block']->region;
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__' . $variables['block']->module;
  // Hyphens (-) and underscores (_) play a special role in theme suggestions.
  // Theme suggestions should only contain underscores, because within
  // drupal_find_theme_templates(), underscores are converted to hyphens to
  // match template file names, and then converted back to underscores to match
  // pre-processing and other function names. So if your theme suggestion
  // contains a hyphen, it will end up as an underscore after this conversion,
  // and your function names won't be recognized. So, we need to convert
  // hyphens to underscores in block deltas for the theme suggestions.
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__' . $variables['block']->module . '__' . strtr($variables['block']->delta, '-', '_');
```

You can create some of the suggestions as a .tpl file in your theme, or just a basic block.tpl.php in your theme